# Ts-Jest Typescript diagnostic: error TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ts-jest

I am using ts-jest in a vue project that contains a mixture of js and ts files. The project uses the `@` character for relative mapping of imports to the directory `src/renderer/`. TS is throwing warnings for cannot find module. I am able to ignore the warning and run the tests by doing:

```
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      /* Fails on mapped import syntax without this.*/
      diagnostics: {
        ignoreCodes: ['2307'],
      },
    },
  },
```

but I would like the import to function as intended.

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/renderer/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>', '<rootDir>/src/renderer'],
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/vue-test-setup.ts'],
  snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
  testMatch: ['**/test/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__test__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/?!(vue-timers)'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      /* Fails on mapped import syntax without this.*/
      diagnostics: {
        warnOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The test lies in `test/unit/regexes.spec.ts`
and the import lies in `src/renderer/resources/regexes.ts`

The specific error I get is:

```
 FAIL  test/unit/specs/regexes.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    test/unit/specs/regexes.spec.ts:1:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/resources/regexes'.

    1 import REGEX from '@/resources/regexes';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You seem to mention `resources/regexes` in some places and and `resources/regex` in others, are you sure there is not a typo?

Comment: Yes that was a typo... interestingly, the tests do succeed at run time.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your `tsconfig.json`, then

Comment: got the same error, any chance to know how you fixed it ?

Comment: @y_nk the globals config at the top can selectively ignore typescript diagnostics. I included how to ignore the diagnostic in the question. It doesn't fix the problem but it allows the tests to run.

Comment: @JohnSnow i fixed my issue by removing regex syntax from the keys of the moduleMapper. if that can help 